# Using enum type inside interface in C#

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I have a method of type IEnumerable in one of my classes:

```
protected virtual IEnumerable<T> GetSomething(CrudOptions crudOptions)
{
    ...
}
```

Somewhere in the solution I have defined CrudOptions as:

```
namespace myProject.Enums 
{ 
    public enum CrudOptions { Delete, Update, Read, Create }
}
```

When I'm trying to add the method in my class to an already existing interface class, it tells me I can't do it because the type or namespace `CrudOptions` could not be found.
This is what I'm adding to the interface class:

```
IEnumerable<SomeTypeClass> GetSomething(CrudOptions crudOptions);
```

Am I having this problem because I'm not referencing the CrudOptions type properly, or in an interface I'm not allowed to use a defined type?

Comment: Does your interface have a `using myProject.Enums` statement?

Comment: To isolate the problem, try using the fully-qualified type name, e.g. `IEnumerable<SomeTypeClass> GetSomething(myProject.Enums.CrudOptions crudOptions);`

Comment: there is no limitation to using enum types with interfaces, if that's what you suspect. it is a namespace resolution issue like any other.

Comment: Yes I added that, but still the Enums is underlined with red showing this error: The type or nameSpace name 'Enums' does not exist in the namespace 'myProject'.. @adityap

Comment: are these in two separate projects? does a build fail as well, or is it only intellisense thinking with a stale cache?

Comment: @dlatikay yes they're in two separate projects, sorry I didnt mention. And no, I havent built it yet because I have other issues to fix in other classes as well

Comment: You might want to try building the other project and also see if it's referenced in the one you are trying to use the enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, it seems that the `CrudOptions` enum is not defined in the same project that you have the `GetSomething` method and it sound like the latter project does not have the former project as a reference. The project that has `GetSomething` must reference the project that defines `CrudOptions`.

To add the project reference, go to Solution Explorer, expand the project that has `GetSomething`, right click `References` and select `Add reference...`, select the `Projects` tab on the left in the Reference Manager window, check the box next to the project that defines `CrudOptions`, and click `OK`.

After doing that, in `GetSomething` see if you can compile using the fully qualified type name `myProject.Enums.CrudOptions`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are not using the right namespace. change it like

```
IEnumerable<SomeTypeClass> GetSomething(myProject.Enums.CrudOptions crudOptions);
```

Again, if that's defined in another assembly then you must reference that assembly

Answer (score 0):

I think - just like others told you - there could be multiple problems:

- Duplicate enum type - solution: use fully qualified name
- Not referenced project with enum type - Solution: add reference to project with enum type
- Not builded project -Solution: build project
- Last thing I can imagine is you need to clean up binaries - Solution: delete bin, obj folders in projects and rebuild

This is mainly summarization of all answers above. Hopes this help.